# What is the generic word to specify "rides" in amusement park?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any common word that can be used for all types of rides in an amusement park?

For example, in theme parks, there are different kind of rides like Swing, roller coaster etc. Calling them "rides" doesn't sound correct (or maybe it is correct). So is there any generic word for them?

Comment: _Rides_ is indeed the most common term.

Comment: How about *attractions*?

Comment: *Attractions* would include static displays such as game rooms and "fun houses", and the theater-like things in the Disney parks, eg.  Otherwise it's *rides*, if you're being somehow transported by the thing.

Comment: Some things in an amusement park are rides. Some are attractions. The park has both rides and attractions.

Comment: What don't you like about "rides"?  I mean, why do you think it doesn't sound correct?

Comment: Ok, I just thought that "Rides" is not the correct word. I thought that roller coasters and other stuff like that come in the category of "Rides". But considering your comments, I will use the word "Rides" next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something more general than "attractions," perhaps "features" or, to remain true to your scope, "amusements."