# A general word for for playground toys/rides/apparatus

Tags: single-word-requests

When my children return home from the park, I like to ask them

> Which _____ did you play on?

usually filling the blank with "**things**" for lack of a better word.

a **ride** might work for a see-saw or a merry-go-round (carousel) - basically anything that moves, but that won't work for a slide and certainly not for monkey bars etc.

(This question has been [asked about amusement parks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350936/what-is-the-generic-word-to-specify-rides-in-amusement-park), but I believe that "rides" is appropriate for most things found there).

Comment: Do you mean *park* in the sense of a child's playground?

Comment: @tchrist yes I do. I haven't seen any adult playgrounds in my life (Eastern U.S.) Maybe a teenaged playground.

Comment: 'Swings and things'.

Comment: You describe equipment, but a smaller word would be better for youngsters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["Equipment"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/equipment) is the word used most commonly in American English to describe the apparatus used by children at a playground.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playground), for instance:

> "Modern playgrounds often have recreational equipment such as the seesaw, merry-go-round, swingset, slide, jungle gym, chin-up bars, sandbox, spring rider, trapeze rings, playhouses, and mazes, many of which help children develop physical coordination, strength, and flexibility, as well as providing recreation and enjoyment and supporting social and emotional development. Common in modern playgrounds are play structures that link many different pieces of equipment.
>
> "Public playground equipment refers to equipment intended for use in the play areas of parks, schools, childcare facilities, institutions, multiple family dwellings, restaurants, resorts, and recreational developments, and other areas of public use."

Even very young children should become familiar with the word equipment.

Comment: "What equipment did you play on?" is correct, and arguably suitable for many children.  In the United States, at least in the case of young children, it may be more natural to simply ask "What did you go on (at the park)?" or "What did you play on?"